Buck converter node equation
In section (a) in the picture given below, while the switch is conducting the capacitor is charging so the ic= (il) - (v/R).
While the switch is not conducting, section b, the capacitor should be discharging isn't it? Based on that I have 2 question as below:

In both circuits in the picture (a, b) the capacitor current is shown as it is charging because the the way of the current is shown same. Why?
Considering the capacitor is discharging in (b), ic = (v/R)- (il), is this node equation correct?


Source: https://elprivod.nmu.org.ua/files/converters/Robert_Erikson_fundamentals-of-power-electronics-3n_2020.pdf

The "sense" of the "defining" current ic(t) is the same. It is not said that the current is the "same" (charging) ...

The current equation is exactly the same for both scenarios i.e. \$I_C =  I_L - \frac{V}{R}\$. Or, putting it another way, \$I_L =  I_C + \frac{V}{R}\$ (more clearer).
Any part of the equation does not assume a polarity hence, when you ask this: -

In both circuits in the picture (a, b) the capacitor current is shown as it is charging because the the way of the current is shown same. Why?

You might be missing the detail of what is happening...
For a standard buck converter using a flyback diode, the inductor current (if non-zero) is always feeding the capacitor/load with energy. This happens in scenario (a) and scenario (b), except that in scenario (b), once the current from the inductor falls to zero, the capacitor is exclusively supplying current to the load. Inductor current won't go negative.

Considering the capacitor is discharging in (b)...

As soon as scenario (b) is entered the inductor continues charging the capacitor/load until it's energy store is depleted. For synchronous buck converters, the inductor current will reverse of course and the capacitor will discharge.
But, none of this changes the equation.

Isn’t it so, that when the inductor current falls below Io (average inductor current), it is the capacitor which is discharging and supplying current to the load?

If capacitor is charged in both cases and node equations are same , a question about charge balance arise which is here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/731192/buck-converter-capacitor-voltage-slope  @Andy aka

@Tyassin are you trying to hint that I've said something incorrect in my answer?

@Mhan I haven't exactly said that so, what is your comment about? Why are you linking me to a new question and implying that the new question is somehow connected. I'm answering your question above and, if I find the time I will try and answer your newer question.

@Andy aka Nope…..I should have stated it more clearly as a question.

@Tyassin what is your question?

@Andy aka
I read your post again and it is clear to me now.

Thank you for your answer. In previous old questions, you say ''I answer your question, you ask another question, open a new question' ', I open another question, and now you say 'why are you directing me to another question' I really don't understand.  Anyway, you said that equations are exatly same for both , if so How will the charge balance be in case of same node equation ? there should be negative slope and positive slope for charge balance @Andy aka  for this question I opened a new question

@Mhan the equation remains the same for all scenarios. In other words the current entering a node equals the current leaving the node (Kirchhoff's current law). But, if you expect that simple equation to be somewhat more meaningful for a buck converter you'll be disappointed. I ask why you were directing me to another question because I don't see the relevance of it until you grasp the basic truth of the KCL formula. You seem to think that formula will change in scenario (b) but it doesn't. So, in effect your new question is just this question rewritten because you don't understand the answer.

I understand your answer, I am saying if the node equation is same, How will the charge balance be in case of same node equation ? @ Andy aka you can see  what I mean in my other question

@Mhan what charge balance are you referring to. I see you refer to it in your newer question but, what specifically do you mean for this question and what is confusing you? Please define what you mean by charge balance.

Okay I have no other question here, you can understand what I mean in my new question which I gave the link of it  @Andy aka

@Mhan I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by charge balance. Please define what you mean by charge balance if it's of relevance to this question or, if it isn't relevant then please explain how this question has not been correctly answered.

I got my answer for this question, it is okay, thank you. You can see what I mean for charge balance in my other question which I gave the link of it @Andy aka

@Mhan if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
